# iterm2 badge keeps disappearing

Tags: terminal, iterm

Using iTerm2 Build 3.50beta4 and macOS Monterey noticed that the badge in the window keeps disappearing. It seems to only appear when resizing the window and only while ssh'd into a remote server. Even if I exit out of the remote server, the badge doesn't re-appear. Any idea what may be causing this?

Here's an example of the bug in action:

[image]

I tried changing color themes but no luck. That's the only thing I've changed in the last 30 days when I noticed the issue starting to happen.

Comment: What is the code or setting for the badge. Also it is a beta - does release iTerm show this?

Comment: Going back to the stable version did the trick. Thanks a lot.